# Create CSV file of domain groups and their users

Tags: python, windows

I'm fairly new to scripting in Python. I'm looking for suggestions on improving any of the following in the below script: my coding style, performance, readability, commenting, or anything else.

```
"""
META
Author: James Nicholson
Date: 8/16/2013

DESCRIPTION
This script takes a list of groups from a text file and creates a new text file
in CSV format that contains group members in the below format:

group_name1,user_name1
group_name1,user_name2
etc...

VARIABLES
server = 'domain name'
glist = 'path to text file containing desired groups'
"""

# Import the win32 module needed for accessing groups and members
import win32net

# Set server name and group_list text file variables
server = # enter server name here
group_list = 'groups.txt'
grps = []

# Loop over lines in group_list and store group names in a list
with open(group_list, 'rb') as my_groups:
    for line in my_groups:
        grps.append(line.rstrip('\r\n'))

# Loop over groups and store members in desired format in new text file 'groups_members_output.txt'
with open('groups_members_output.txt', 'wb') as blank_file:
    for group in grps:
        usrs = win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(server,group,0)
        for user in usrs[0]:
            blank_file.write('{},{}\r\n'.format(group,user['name']))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some notes:

- Comments: A lot (if not all) of the comments are pretty much repeating what the code already says. I'd remove them.
- `server = # enter server name here`. Create functions with configurable elements as arguments instead of global variables.
- `with open('groups_members_output.txt', 'wb') as blank_file`. Try to give more meaningful names to variables, be declarative. `blank_file` says hardly anything useful about the variable.
- `grps`/`usrs`: Just for saving one or two characters now variables are harder to read.
- Put spaces after commas.
- Use (functional) list-comprehensions expressions instead of (imperative) for-loop statements whenever possible.
- Use always `"\n"` for line endings (read and write), Python takes care of [portability in all platforms](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.linesep).

I'd write:

```
import win32net

def write_group_members(server, input_groups, output_groups):
    with open(input_groups) as input_groups_fd:
        groups = [line.rstrip() for line in input_groups_fd]

    with open(output_groups, "w") as output_groups_fd:
        for group in groups:
            users = win32net.NetGroupGetUsers(server, group, 0)[0]
            for user in users:
                contents = "{0},{1}\n".format(group, user["name"])
                output_groups_fd.write(contents)

write_group_members("someserver.org", "groups.txt", "groups_members_output.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a huge improvement on my original code. How do I actually execute the code if it is written with functions instead of just a script with global variables? Would I need to place the .py file in my site-packages directory so I could import it into the interpreter?

Comment: Use the [`if __name__ == '__main__'` idiom](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/493/11227)

Answer (score 2):

The code looks good (it's short, which is always a good thing).

Make sure to follow PEP 8. A [recent revision of PEP 8](http://hg.python.org/peps/rev/fb24c80e9afb) allowed 99 characters lines to "improve readability", but your `# Loop over ...` comment would still be easier to read on small screens (or on CodeReview!) if splitted.

An issue I often deal with myself in `for entity in collection` statements is naming properly `entity` and `collection` when you really can't provide distinct names. I don't think `group/grps` is a good choice. I'd suggest `group/group_list`, while renaming `group_list` to `group_filename` or something similar. [PEP 20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) says "Explicit is better than implicit." very early.

Your comments could be improved too: a common advice to beginners is to avoid stating what the line i (eg. `# increment n`), but say what it means (eg. `# adding a new unit`). You're actually doing both: you just have to remove the useless part!

- `# Loop over lines in group_list and store group names in a list` becomes `# Store group names in a list`
- `# Import the win32 module needed for accessing groups and members` becomes `# Accessing groups and members`.

Comment: Very helpful, especially the part about improving my comments.